# Can't add shortcut key to zoomin/out in mircosoft word on my Macbook

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, zoom

In Tools > Customise Keyboard > View > ViewZoomIn, there are no current keys and I can't assign a new keyboard shortcut, what I want to do is to zoom in and out using Ctrl + scroll +- which I switch from the window has this shortcut in any application.

Comment: Ctrl/scroll is macOS default for 'zoom entire screen'. Try Cmd/+ & Cmd/- which is more usually used for individual page zoom. I would be surprised if MS can use scrollwhell for that type of function.

Comment: Please check whether the article "[How To Zoom On Mac](https://setapp.com/how-to/zoom-on-mac)" is helpful.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is it possible to customized change Cmd/+- to Cmd/scroll

Comment: @Emily It is teaching how to zoom the entire screen, I want to zoom specific window or application instead.

Comment: I doubt it, as already mentioned. There's no way to do it in the OS, & MS are even less Mac-standard.

Comment: You could record macros for particular zooms and assign keyboard shortcuts to those macros. Not the same as up and down but it may help.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon How can I record the macros and assign keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-run-a-macro-c6b99036-905c-49a6-818a-dfb98b7c3c9c.